# ROS Camera Calibration Cannot Find set_camera_info Service

Tags: camera, ros, camera-calibration

I am new to ROS and am trying to run the camera calibration program. I got the cv_camera module to publish the `/cv_camera/camera_info`, `/cv_camera/image_raw` I ran `rosservice list` which showed that the `/cv_camera/set_camera_info` is running. Yet when I run the calibrator.py script, it fails saying:

```
[WARN] [1612648019.937615]: wait_for_service(/cv_camera_node/set_camera_info): failed to contact, will keep trying
Service not found
QMutex: destroying locked mutex
QMutex: destroying locked mutex
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Here is was `rostopic list` shows:

```
/cv_camera/camera_info
/cv_camera/image_raw
/cv_camera_node/camera_info
/cv_camera_node/image_raw
/rosout
/rosout_agg
```

Here is was `rosservice list` shows:

```
/cv_camera/get_loggers
/cv_camera/set_camera_info
/cv_camera/set_logger_level
/cv_camera_node/get_loggers
/cv_camera_node/set_camera_info
/cv_camera_node/set_logger_level
/rosout/get_loggers
/rosout/set_logger_level
```

I am using ROS Noetic and my server is running on a Ubuntu 20.04 VM. My camera is on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ and is using s Picamera V2. Any help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have to add the image_common module!

Comment: `rosdep install image_common` and `sudo apt install ros-melodic-image-common` installed successfully, but did not change the error.